# Mac OS OpenGL screen grab

Tags: c++, macos, opengl

I'm trying capture mac os desktop by OpenGL i.e GL desktop grabbing.

```
CGContextRef bitmap;
CGImageRef image;
void * data;
long bytewidth;
GLint width, height;
long bytes;
CGColorSpaceRef cSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB);
CGLContextObj    glContextObj;
CGLPixelFormatObj pixelFormatObj ;
GLint            numPixelFormats ;

int attribs[] =
{
    kCGLPFAFullScreen,
    kCGLPFADisplayMask,
    NULL,
    kCGLPFAColorSize, 24,
    kCGLPFAAlphaSize, 0,
    kCGLPFADepthSize, 32,
    NULL
};

CGDirectDisplayID display;
if(display == kCGNullDirectDisplay)
{
    display = CGMainDisplayID();
}

attribs[2] = CGDisplayIDToOpenGLDisplayMask(display);

CGLChoosePixelFormat( (CGLPixelFormatAttribute*) attribs, &pixelFormatObj, &numPixelFormats );
if ( pixelFormatObj == NULL )    // No full screen context support
{
    attribs[10] = NULL;
    CGLChoosePixelFormat( (CGLPixelFormatAttribute*) attribs, &pixelFormatObj, &numPixelFormats );
    if (pixelFormatObj == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
}
CGLCreateContext( pixelFormatObj, NULL, &glContextObj ) ;
CGLDestroyPixelFormat( pixelFormatObj ) ;
if ( glContextObj == NULL )
{
   return;
}

CGLSetCurrentContext( glContextObj ) ;
CGLSetFullScreen( glContextObj ) ;

glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT);

width = scrWidth;
height = srcHeight;

bytewidth = width * 4; // Assume 4 bytes/pixel for now
bytewidth = (bytewidth + 3) & ~3; // Align to 4 bytes
bytes = bytewidth * height; // width * height

data = malloc(height * bytewidth);
if ( data == NULL )
{
    CGLSetCurrentContext( NULL );
    CGLClearDrawable( glContextObj ); // disassociate from full screen
    CGLDestroyContext( glContextObj ); // and destroy the context
    return;
}
bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, width, height, 8, bytewidth,
                               cSpace, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst /* XRGB */);
CFRelease(cSpace);

glFinish(); 
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 4);
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ROW_LENGTH, 0);
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_SKIP_ROWS, 0);
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_SKIP_PIXELS, 0);

glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height,
             GL_RGB,
  #ifdef __BIG_ENDIAN__
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, // for PPC
  #else
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, // for Intel!
  #endif
             data);

swizzleBitmap(data, bytewidth, height);

image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);

CFRelease(bitmap);
free(data);

CGLSetCurrentContext( NULL );
CGLClearDrawable( glContextObj );
CGLDestroyContext( glContextObj );
```

But I'm getting black images. 
I'm using 10.10.3 OS X Yosemite .
What the problem can be here? 
maybe problem is in mac os version?

I'm writing pixel data into the file by glReadPixels but without result, again black images.

Answer (score 3):

OpenGL can not be used reliably for screen capturing. The "OpenGL screen capture examples" that do the fullscreen-window-glReadPixels thing rely on undefined behavior of the underlying graphics system. Namely that windows share the screen framebuffer and that a newly created window without a erasure brush will "inherit" the contents of the screen where it was created.

On modern graphics systems all these assumptions fail:

- Windows *don't* share the screen framebuffer
- Windows *always* are initialized with some clearing brush
- Windows are composited into the final desktop appearance

Comment: Thanks for this information.
i.e for Mac screen grabbing I must use standard functions like
CGDisplayCreateImageForRect, CGImageGetDataProvider ... ?

Comment: @GeorgGPU: Yes, you must use the standard system functions for this.